# Free WHOIS web service

Tags: gratis, web-apps, internet

I am looking for a web service that gives WHOIS information for a domain.

I would like this service to meet these requirements:

- Gratis
- Stable
- Includes the following information in a query

  - Registration date
  - Expiration date
  - DNS information

Comment: Have you tried any services,  or is this your first attempt/search?

Answer (score 2):

Unless I've got your idea wrong, there are many websites that offer this service. Try googling "domain whois" and in my case the whole first page was valid (I didn't go any further)

Anyway - my recommendation:

## http://whois.icann.org/

I tested google.com

> #### Dates
>
> Updated Date: 2015-06-12
>
> Created Date: 1997-09-15
>
> Registration Expiration Date: 2020-09-14
>
> '

By DNS I imagine you mean Nameservers?

> #### Nameservers
>
> ns4.google.com
>
> ns1.google.com
>
> ns3.google.com
>
> ns2.google.com

Here is the link to the google.com results:

http://whois.icann.org/en/lookup?name=google.com